# Complicated group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a homework, where we are given `IEnumerable<Movie>` 
where Movie contains `HashSet<string> genres` (list of genres represented by string like "Comedy", "Drama" etc.).

How to use LINQ and group by to sort movies by genre?
(create `IGrouping<string, IEnumerable<Movie>>`)

Comment: I would just vlike to recommend this site for this and other Linq questions: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to flatten out the movies into move/genre pairs first, *then* group:

```
var grouped = from movie in movies
              from genre in movie.Genres
              group movie by genre;
```

Or avoiding query expressions:

```
var grouped = movies.SelectMany(movie => move.Genres,
                                (movie, genre) => new { movie, genre })
                    .GroupBy(pair => pair.genre, pair => pair.movie);
```